# Joining 2 CSV tables together

Tags: python, csv

So I basically want to read 2 csv files containing with the result:
I just want the tables stacked next to each other.
I would apreciate some code that would do it for more than 2 csv files.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq1Rk.png)

Comment: Take a look at the [pandas library](https://www.learndatasci.com/tutorials/python-pandas-tutorial-complete-introduction-for-beginners/) and check out [this excellent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read pandas documentation. It gives all you need to know https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('a.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('b.csv')

print(pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, sort=False))
```